# Stop HTML list items from adjusting on hover

Tags: html, list, sass, hover, styles

I am working on creating an HTML list where when the user hovers over elements of the list, the selected element enlarges through an increase in `font-size`.
This works perfectly, however the enlarged element pushes the other elements in the list up/down, which makes it look pretty weird.

How can I ensure that the other elements don't adjust to the enlarged element?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<ol>List:
  <div class = "center">
    <li>IT</li>
    <li>Some Element 1</li>
    <li>Some Element 2</li>
    <li>Some Element 3</li>
    <li>Websites in einer Stunde</li>
    <li>Professioneller Website Kritiker</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
li:hover{
  font-size:120%;
}
li:hover:before{
  font-size:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a fixed height

```css
li {
  list-style-type: circle;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li:hover {
  font-size: 120%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li:hover:before {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ol>List:
  <div class="center">
    <li>IT</li>
    <li>Some Element 1</li>
    <li>Some Element 2</li>
    <li>Some Element 3</li>
    <li>Websites in einer Stunde</li>
    <li>Professioneller Website Kritiker</li>
  </div>
</ol>
```